# render default src img if there is no image data fetched from database in react js

Tags: reactjs

i`m trying to render a component, which if there is no fetched data from database it will render the imported image, this is my code.

```
import userDefault from '../../../assets/userDefault.png
<img src={profile?userPhoto ? profile?.userPhoto : userDefault} alt="User-Image" />
```

how can i render  `userDefault` if the profile.userPhoto value is null?

Comment: I guess dot is missing while accessing  userPhoto from profile object in your code shown here or it might be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation looks fine to me, just sharing the improved code below

#### JSX

```
<img src={profile?.userPhoto ? profile.userPhoto : userDefault} alt="User-Image" />
```

**2nd Approach Using OR Operator (||)**

JavaScript OR Operator tries to find first truthy value so if database image exists then it will render it, if  not then it will render your default image

#### JSX

```
<img src={profile?.userPhoto || userDefault} alt="User-Image" />
```